# Validator returning a list when using UserFormInput

Tags: flutter, user-interface

As the title says I would like to return a List instead of a String. Why? Well I have a "Register account screen" where I want to have validation that displays things like: "Password is too short", "You can't have special characters", "Your password must include a number", etc...
My code does this by displaying one error at a time, taking the first element in a list of errors. I want it to display all the errors at the same time, like this:

[Validation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqIVq.png)

And not like it currently does it:

[Validation, only one error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsMrS.png)

Is using the validator the best solution or should I create my own "Scaffold"? Or what would be the best solution?

My code:

```
UserFormInput(
                      controller: passwordController,
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      hint: 'Enter Your Password',
                      isPassword: _passwordVisible,
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          !_passwordVisible
                              ? Icons.visibility
                              : Icons.visibility_off,
                          color: Color(0xff868686),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      validator: (password) {
                        var message = model.validatePassword(password);
                        return message;
                      },
),
```

As I said above the validatePassword(password) returns a String with the first error in a list of all errors.

A little side note. I am new to flutter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything like what you want in flutter built-in, but you can make it. It can be made with couple of `Text` and `Icon` widgets and manually validating entered string on OnChanged of the `TextField`.